# Why I can not call initCause() at creation of an instance or throwing an exception

Tags: java, exception

I don't understand why I can't just `initCause()` in the same line I creating an instance or throw an exception. If I put it on the same line, the compiler thinks that method must throw a throwable object.

```
// All exceptions in the example are subclass of Exception class;
private static void throwException() throws BadCodeException {
    throw new BadCodeException("Actual cause");
}

private static void rethrowException() throws BadProgramException{
    try {
        throwException();
    } catch (BadCodeException e) {
        BadProgramException ex = new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred");
        ex.initCause(e);
        throw ex;
    } /* catch (BadCodeException e) { // Compiler tells about unhandled Throwable;
        throw new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred").initCause(e);
    } */
```

Also, I will be glad if somebody told me is it right usage of chained exceptions or not, because it is only I found.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  What error are you seeing (or not seeing)?

Comment: `initCause` has return type `Throwable`. So if you `throw` the result of `initCause`, then (as far as the compiler can tell), your method might throw any kind of `Throwable`.

Comment: 'Error:(33, 13) java: unreported exception java.lang.Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown'

Comment: @khelwood got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by khelwood, `initCause` has a declared return type of `Throwable` (check the API docs). So if you throw the result of `initCause`, then (as far as the compiler can tell), your method might throw any kind of `Throwable`.

To answer your other question, the normal way to do chained exceptions is

```
throw new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred", e);
```

and then add another constructor to `BadProgramException` if it doesn't have such a constructor, which simply calls `super` with its two arguments.

That approach doesn't have this problem. You would only need to call `initCause` if `BadProgramException` is a legacy class that you couldn't modify to add an extra constructor to.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is the signature:

```
public synchronized Throwable initCause(Throwable cause);
```

As you can see, the return type here is `Throwable`;

Doing it in one line equals to:

```
// Throwable is not BadProgramException! It's wider type
private static void rethrowException() throws BadProgramException {
    try {
        throwException();
    } catch (BadCodeException e) {
        BadProgramException ex = new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred");
        Throwable throwable = ex.initCause(e);
        throw throwable;
    }
}
```

What requires additional handling. You changing **the reference type** doing it in one line. Your method does not throwing `BadProgramException` any more. It's throwing **wider**, top type of exception.

Doing it in one line does not change the reference type:

```
private static void rethrowException() throws BadProgramException {
    try {
        throwException();
    } catch (BadCodeException e) {
        BadProgramException ex = new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred");
        ex.initCause(e);
        throw ex; // Reference type is still BadProgramException and matches current signature
    }
}
```

Basically one-line call could be solved like:

```
private static void rethrowException() throws Throwable {
    try {
        throwException();
    } catch (BadCodeException e) {
        BadProgramException ex = new BadProgramException("Problem that occurred");
        throw ex.initCause(e);
    }
}
```

But this is not a good approach to throwing superclass of all errors like `Throwable`. You need to throw the narrowest possible exception type.